# command "subl" from terminal don't work

Tags: terminal, sublimetext2, osx-mountain-lion

I am a Mac-newbie (Mountain Lion) and try to set up the "subl"-command for the terminal, like described here:

> The first task is to make a symlink to subl. Assuming you've placed
>   Sublime Text 2 in the Applications folder, and that you have a ~/bin
>   directory in your path, you can run:
>
> ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text
>   2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl

But it doesn't work. I have now a folder /bin/ under my user and this folder including a alias. But when I tip in `subl --help` inside the terminal, I get the error `-bash: subl: command not found`

Can someone helps me out?

KR & thx, Fabian

Comment: Do you have `~/bin` as one of the directories in your `$PATH` variable?  If not, then you would get the error.  Many people have `$HOME/bin` or `~/bin` as one of the directories on their `$PATH`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have found the solution now - there was a problem with RVM. The solution is to enter the command

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/.rvm/bin/subl
```

into the terminal.

Comment: Why is rvm causing issues with this? Could you explain?

Comment: @nilbus no I could not, sorry. I am still a beginner in programming

Comment: It turns out this solution stopped working after my next login.

Comment: It solved the problem for me, though I have no idea why: adding a Sublime symlink to other folders in PATH doesn't have that effect.

Comment: I had this issue with RVM and this worked perfectly for me. I was ripping my hair out prior to discovering this. Thank you!

Comment: Did people really had problems with RVM and sublime? This makes no sense, you should just add it to your path. If you really want to link it, use `~/bin/` instead.

Answer (score 87):

Change directories to:

```
/usr/local/bin
```

then run this instead:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" subl
```

Comment: I had to use a modified version for Sublime Text 3: .../Application/Sublime Text.app/...

Comment: nice answer. however, I needed to run this command as super user. i.e. sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" subl

Comment: Thank you for noting that I had to be in a different directory than I was currently in. I'm a relative newbie and probably wouldn't have figured that out. You helped a lot.

Comment: the link is created, but it is not runnable. ls command shows it is there, but typing s on the command line and trying to autocomplete does not work, and running it fails.

Answer (score 28):

That happened to me with [Sublime Text 3](https://www.sublimetext.com/3).

This symlink works for me, only I needed was to change the symlink destination to **/usr/local/bin/subl**

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Solution source [Paul Byrne answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26931544/subl-command-not-working-properly?rq=1)

Comment: I got a permission denied error. So you generally need a sudo with it.

Answer (score 9):

Using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install Sublime usually creates the correct symlinks automatically.

```
brew install Caskroom/cask/sublime-text
```

Subl can then be accessed like:

```
# Open Sublime at current directory
subl .
```

Comment: I recently tried this again, and it appears the command has been change to `subl`.

Answer (score 3):

The solution chosen for this question is to put the subl symlink in the ~/.rvm/bin folder which is definitely not a generic solution as this directory is part of a program he has installed.

Although any directory in the path will work, the most common solution is to create a bin directory in the home folder, set it in the path by putting `export PATH=$PATH:~/bin` in .bash_profile and then running the link command as shown in the original question with this new path.

In the past it was common to put the subl symlink in /usr/local/bin but this directory no longer exists in OSX as of version 10.2 and the /usr/local directory is no longer in the default path.

Answer (score 3):

## **SOLVED for MAC OSX Mavericks!**

I found this answer on this GitHubGist:
https://gist.github.com/artero/1236170

### Launch Sublime Text 2 from the Mac OS X Terminal

```
ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/sublime
```

This is the part that I found clarified what many StackOverflow responses have only hinted at, but not explicitly explained:

> Now let's do a check to see if everything will run smoothly. Enter this:
>
> open ~/.bash_profile
>
> (In some cases the profile file is named ~/.profile)
>
> You should see at the top of the file a line that starts with: export PATH=
>
> This contains all the directories that will be looked into for executable binaries when you type a command in Terminal. Since we create a symlink to subl called sublime in the /usr/local/bin directory let's check if this directory is listed on that same line.
>
> If it is, perfect. Let's keep going. If not, simply add it like this and save the file:
>
> export PATH=/usr/local/bin:(...)
>
> Note: The '(...)' in this example represents other folders that would be listed on the same line and separated by a colon.
>
> If you don't already have a PATH set in your bash_profile you can type:
>
> export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
>
> If you had to add /usr/local/bin to your PATH, run the following command before continuing:
>
> source ~/.bash_profile
>
> This will reload your .bash_profile with the newly added directory.
>
> Testing
>
> Open a Terminal window and run:
>
> sublime filename (replace "filename" by an actual file name)

Hope that helps clarify for others as well. Currently (FALL 2014) using Mac OSX Mavericks. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the **command to open files using sublime text**, and you're not bothered to use it as your default editor for all commands, why not just add an alias to your `~/.bash-profile` ?

```
alias subl="open -a 'Sublime Text'"
```

That will work for opening files and directories

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem on a MAC with OSX Yosemite 10.10.5, and sublime text 3 Build 3083!

Configuring git to work with the above requirements worked perfectly using:

```
git config --global core.editor "/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl -n -w"
```

And test if it worked with:

```
git config -e
```

Answer (score 1):

It works on Mac OSX 10.8.2, **echo $PATH** shows subl symlink correctly linked as described in this post. The other suggestions on Sublime Text 2 page seem not work with new Macs

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that there was an alias for subl. Type `alias` to see all defined aliases. Find the source and comment it out, or use `unalias subl` to unset.

Answer (score 0):

For .bashrc or .zshrc

```
alias subl="open . -a /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app"
```

Answer (score 0):

Catalina's auto-sandboxing seems to broke the `subl` command.

Use the following alias as an alternative

```
alias subl="open $1 -b com.sublimetext.3"
```

Answer (score -1):

After `$ subl .` did not work for me,

I tried `$ bundle exec subl .` and it worked.

**Solution: type `$ bundle exec subl .` and it should work.** (Obviously, omitting the $)